# PyTorch: "KeyError: Caught KeyError in DataLoader worker process 0."

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, pytorch, dataset

#### Problem Description

I tried to load image data using a PyTorch custom dataset, however, I received the error message listed below. After its occurrence, I checked the data and found that my image set consists of 2 types of shape (512,512,3) and (1024,1024). My assumption is that the error is related to this.

Note: The code is able to read some of the images but throws the error message for others.

#### Questions

1. How should one preprocess such image data for training?
2. Are there any other reasons for the error message?

#### Error message

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-163-aa3385de8026> in <module>
----> 1 train_features, train_labels = next(iter(train_dataloader))
  2 print(f"Feature batch shape: {train_features.size()}")
  3 print(f"Labels batch shape: {train_labels.size()}")
  4 img = train_features[0].squeeze()
  5 label = train_labels[0]

 ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils  /data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
519             if self._sampler_iter is None:
520                 self._reset()
521             data = self._next_data()
522             self._num_yielded += 1
523             if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
1201             else:
1202                 del self._task_info[idx]
1203                 return self._process_data(data)
1204 
1205     def _try_put_index(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _process_data(self, data)
1227         self._try_put_index()
1228         if isinstance(data, ExceptionWrapper):
1229             data.reraise()
1230         return data
1231 

~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/_utils.py in reraise(self)
423             # have message field
424             raise self.exc_type(message=msg)
425         raise self.exc_type(msg)
426 
427 

KeyError: Caught KeyError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas  /core/indexes/base.py", line 2898, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1032, in    pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1039, in   pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 16481

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 287, in _worker_loop
data = fetcher.fetch(index)
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
File "<ipython-input-161-f38b78d77dcb>", line 19, in __getitem__
img_path =os.path.join(self.img_dir,self.image_ids[idx])
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 882, in __getitem__
return self._get_value(key)
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 990, in _get_value
loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2900, in get_loc
raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 16481
```

#### Code

```py
from torchvision.io import read_image
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

class CustomImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataset, transforms=None, target_transforms=None):
        #self.train_data = pd.read_csv("Data/train_data.csv")
        self.image_ids = dataset.image_id
        self.image_labels = dataset.label
        self.img_dir = 'Data/images'
        self.transforms = transforms
        self.target_transforms = target_transforms

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_ids)

    def __getitem__(self,idx):
        # image path
        img_path =os.path.join(self.img_dir,self.image_ids[idx])
        # image
        image = read_image(img_path)
        label = self.image_labels[idx]
        # transform image
        if self.transforms:
             image = self.transforms(image)
        # transform target
        if self.target_transforms:
             label = self.target_transforms(label)

    return image, label
```

`train_data` is the pandas object of the csv file which has the image id and label information.

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test = train_test_split(train_data, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)
train_df = CustomImageDataset(X_train)
train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    train_df,
    batch_size=64,
    num_workers=1,
    shuffle=True)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

found the issue with the code.

Pytorch Custom Dataloader function "**getitem**" uses idx to retrieve data and my guess is, it know the range of idx from **len** function, ex: 0, till len(rows in dataset).

In my case, I already had a panda dataset (train_data) with idx as one of the column. When I randomly split it into X_train and X_test, few of the data rows were moved to X_test along with the idx.

Now, when I send X_train to the custom dataloader, it is trying to get row's image_id with an idx and that idx just happens to be in X_test dataset. This lead to error as keyerror: 16481 i.e row with idx=16481 is not present in the X_train dataset. It was moved to X_test during split.

phew...

Comment: You saved my day. I was also indexing based on the dataframe's index and the df_train was obviously lacking some indice since the split. I only needed to reset_index when creating the datasets.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error while fine-tuning the **DistilBertModel** transformers-based model in PyTorch while replacing its head.

I've forgotten to reset the indices of train_dataframe and test_dataframe after train_test_split that caused my `CustomDataset`to index improperly.

You can use Pandas `reset_index` for this before loading your data into your dataloader.

```
traindf.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

or

```
traindf = traindf.reset_index(drop=True)
```